# Drawing curved shapes

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, core-animation

How do I draw/create curved shapes like these:

[image]

Can you point me to some example? Is Core Graphics going to work? I'll also need to animate them so maybe we will need to use Core Animation too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is `UIBezierPath`. Core Graphics will draw along such paths for you, as well as other magic such as masking. Core Animation can move objects along bezier paths too.

Enjoy :)